# Android: flaky ViewModel unit tests with coroutines

Tags: android, kotlin, android-testing, kotlin-coroutines, android-viewmodel

I have a VM such as

```
class CityListViewModel(private val repository: Repository) : ViewModel() {
    @VisibleForTesting
    val allCities: LiveData<Resource<List<City>>> =
        liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + Dispatchers.IO) {
            emit(Resource.Loading())
            emit(repository.getCities())
        }
}
```

And my tests are:

```
@ExperimentalCoroutinesApi
class CityListViewModelTest {
    @get:Rule
    val rule = InstantTaskExecutorRule()
    @get:Rule
    val coroutineTestRule = CoroutinesTestRule()

    @Test
    fun `allCities should emit first loading and then a Resource#Success value`() =
        runBlockingTest {
            val fakeSuccessResource = Resource.Success(
                listOf(
                    City(
                        1,
                        "UK",
                        "London",
                        Coordinates(34.5, 56.2)
                    )
                )
            )
            val observer: Observer<Resource<List<City>>> = mock()
            val repositoryMock: Repository = mock()

            val sut =
                CityListViewModel(repositoryMock)
            doAnswer { fakeSuccessResource }.whenever(repositoryMock).getCities()

            sut.allCities.observeForever(observer)
            sut.allCities
            val captor = argumentCaptor<Resource<List<City>>>()
            captor.run {
                verify(observer, times(2)).onChanged(capture())
                assertEquals(fakeSuccessResource.data, lastValue.data)
            }
        }

    @Test
    fun `allCities should emit first loading and then a Resource#Error value`() =
        runBlockingTest {
            val fakeErrorResource = Resource.Error<List<City>>("Error")
            val observer: Observer<Resource<List<City>>> = mock()
            val repositoryMock: Repository = mock()

            val sut =
                CityListViewModel(repositoryMock)
            doAnswer { fakeErrorResource }.whenever(repositoryMock).getCities()

            sut.allCities.observeForever(observer)
            sut.allCities
            val captor = argumentCaptor<Resource<List<City>>>()
            captor.run {
                verify(observer, times(2)).onChanged(capture())
                assertEquals(fakeErrorResource.data, lastValue.data)
            }
        }
}
```

The problem I have is that the tests are very flaky: sometimes they both pass, sometimes one fails, but I can't seem to find out the problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The issue is that in the test, you don't have control over the IO Dispatcher. I'm assuming your `CoroutinesTestRule` is something like this [Gist](https://gist.github.com/manuelvicnt/049ce057fa6b5e5c785ec9fff7c22a7c)? This only overrides `Dispatchers.Main`, but your `CityListViewModel` uses `Dispatchers.IO`.

There are a few different options:

1. In `CityListViewModel`, you can avoid using `Dispatchers.IO` explicitly, and instead just rely on the `viewModelScope` which defaults to `Dispatchers.Main`. In your real `Repository` implementation, ensure that your suspending `getCities()` method redirects to `Dispatchers.IO`, i.e.

```
suspend fun getCities(): List<City> {
  withContext(Dispatchers.IO) {
    // do work
    return cities
  }
}
```

And in the `CityListViewModel`:

```
  val allCities: LiveData<Resource<List<City>>> = 
    liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext) {
      emit(Resource.Loading())
      emit(repository.getCities())
    }
```

In this case, things will continue to work as they do currently, and in your test, the mock `Repository` will just immediately return a value.

2. Inject `Dispatchers.IO` instead. If you're using a DI framework such as Dagger this will be easier, but you could essentially do something like:

```
class CityListViewModel(
  private val ioDispatcher: CoroutineDispatcher = Dispatchers.IO,
  private val repository: Repository
) : ViewModel() {
  @VisibleForTesting
  val allCities: LiveData<Resource<List<City>>> = 
    liveData(context = viewModelScope.coroutineContext + ioDispatcher) {
      emit(Resource.Loading())
      emit(repository.getCities())
    }
}
```

And then in your test:

```
val viewModel = CityListViewModel(
  ioDispatcher = TestCoroutineDispatcher(),
  repository = repository
)
```

Either of these should make your tests deterministic. If you are using Dagger, then I'd recommend doing both (create a production module to provide the Main, IO, and Default dispatchers, but have a test module that provides instances of `TestCoroutineDispatcher` instead), but also doing option 1 which is to make sure your suspending functions direct the work to another dispatcher if they're doing blocking work.

Comment: thanks a lot, this is a great answer: the cause is very well explained and even solutions provided. you saved my day!

Comment: Any update on it? Cause none of the solution really works!

Answer (score 1):

I believe best approach is to **pass Dispatcher to your viewModels** so testing is super easy.. like here :
https://stackoverflow.com/a/62629410/2719243